# paypal doesn't pass back variables on mobile browser

Tags: .net, vb.net, mobile, paypal

When making a purchase using paypal on a desktop browser I receive all the custom on0 and os0 variables posted back fine, however when completing the paypal transaction using a mobile browser e.g. iphone, ipad, android only a select few variables return so our following process  I carry out does not function correctly.

Using Visual Basic.net

Answer (score 0):

I just spoke with Paypal regarding this and their answer was very generic. Stating that their paypal mobile website is not fully integrated. Yet there is no way to bypass the mobile website in the customer HTML form.